# Dynamically split string in ssrs

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have a string like 0+9948.00000+-4254.39910+38040. I want to split this string by '+' symbol which will give me

```
GetValue(0)= 0
GetValue(1)= 9948.00000
GetValue(2)= -4254.39910
GetValue(3)= 38040
```

but my problem is that the string is dynamic and it can be "0+9948.00000". So this time I'll get #error. Below is the code which I've used as expression.

```
=CInt(Split(Fields!M_BUDV1.Value,"+").GetValue(0))
    + CInt(Split(Fields!M_BUDV1.Value,"+").GetValue(1))
    + CInt(Split(Fields!M_BUDV1.Value,"+").GetValue(2))
    + CInt(Split(Fields!M_BUDV1.Value,"+").GetValue(3))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's a comment. My apologies writing as a answer. I don't have enough reputations to make a comment.
I used the following code for a dynamic delimiter split

```
=Fields!ID.Value.ToString().Replace("+",vbCrLf)
```

[image]